# Populating a JavaScript array with MySql data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I've looked through various other questions on SO, but can't quite get the right answer. Basically, I have an array that needs data from a MySql database. Here's what I've tried:

```
var $name = "Foo",
    $x = 10,
    $bar =
      <? php
        $barQuery = mysql_query("SELECT item FROM table WHERE name = '$name' AND number = '$x'");
        $barArray = array();

        while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($barQuery))
        {
          $barArray[] = $r['item'];
        }

        echo json_encode($barArray);
      ?>;
```

EDIT: I then post this to a .php file, and print the returned data:

```
$.post("file.php", {bar: JSON.stringify($bar), name: $name}).done(function(data)
{
  $('body').html(data);
  window.print();
  setTimeout("location.reload(true)", 500);
});
```

However, I get an error saying "syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE". Is it not possible to populate a JS array this way, or is there another way to do it?

Comment: $name, $x and $bar are javascript vars?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Yes

Comment: Note that you're using a long since deprecated API

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer The reason I use the dollar sign, is because I then post this information to another .php file using `$.post();`

Comment: you should put $bar into " " because is a string

Comment: PHP syntax errors usually specify the line number on which the error occurred—this is extremely helpful information (although you will have to map that to your code snippet for us).

Comment: If `$name` and `$x` are JavaScript variables, then you cannot access them within PHP (which is processed on the server-side, before the JavaScript is even transmitted to the client): therefore they are not defined when used in your SQL.

Comment: @eggyal I could use `$.post()` to post the variables, but how would I then put the returned data into a JS array variable? The same way I do here using `echo`?

Comment: @eggyal The error is showing up at the first line of php, so the line that has `<? php`

Comment: there is any code before the first code in your question?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Yes, but it's only an `if` statement, which this code is nested inside

Comment: do you try with my answer?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Yes, and am getting the same error as commented on eggyal's answer

Comment: and you have any mysql_connect ?

Comment: Yes, I connect to the database before the HTML head, and I also interact with the database in the HTML which works fine. The only issue is this part in the JS. Would it be easier (and better) to use `jQuery.post()` and then use the return data, or stick with it this way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72472/discussion-between-adrian-cid-almaguer-and-michael-jarvis).

Answer (score 0):

```
var $name = "Foo",
    $x = 10,
    $bar = "
      <?php
        $barQuery = mysql_query("SELECT item FROM table WHERE name = '$name' AND number = '$x'");
        $barArray = array();

        while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($barQuery))
        {
          $barArray[] = $r['item'];
        }

        echo json_encode($barArray);
      ?>";
```

Comment: Would this cause any issues since the speech marks cancel out where the SELECT begins?

Comment: I have edited the OP to show what happens next. What else is required?

Comment: @MichaelJarvis you got some advance?

Answer (score 0):

You have a superfluous space inside the PHP opening tag:

```
      <? php
        ^--- this shouldn't be there
```

As it stands, the `<?` is parsed as a short open tag, and so the `php` is parsed as a(n undefined) constant, which is immediately followed by `$barQuery`—hence the syntax error that you see: `unexpected T_VARIABLE`.

Comment: It's always something so simple... Thanks! However, an error in the JS console is saying there is an 'unterminated string literal' when I declare `$bar`

Comment: @MichaelJarvis: That's strange.  Have you changed your code from what it originally was in your question?  Check the JavaScript that is output by PHP (and therefore parsed by the browser); your JS console might help to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Yes, here's what it said: `$bar = "
        <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/page.php</b> on line <b>791</b><br />
[]";` Line 791 is where the `while` loop begins

Comment: @MichaelJarvis: That means that `$barQuery` is false, because `mysql_query()` failed.  You should inspect `mysql_error()`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole